# vim showing special character in bash shell using WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I start to use vim or tmux, I got a lot of special characters showing up as square box with question mark in it. I'm using the builtin bash shell program with consolas font, is there anything wrong with my setup? Here is a link to the screenshot, it appears both in vim and nano. with tmux or without!

*Screenshot of my bash shell vim screen:*
[image]

*Screenshot of my bash shell nano screen:*
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I have the same setup and it is working correctly. The squares with question marks indicate a font issue. Check  the `.vimrc` file for any font / encoding issues.

Comment: I checked my .vimrc and I don't see any font/encoding issue. And I can see the same character when using nano as well! Something wrong with my maching encoding?

Comment: You might get more help with this on the Super User forum....

Comment: I had issues with special characters when using the default _Consolas_ font. Try to change it to _NSimSun_ or if you prefer install a better font (e.g. DejaVuSansMono) from https://nerdfonts.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and the reason was my environment var $TERM was set to screen-256color-bce. After removing that line from my bashrc it just worked fine.
I've asked the question and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063465/vim-tmux-wsl-shows-squares-and-strange-characters-when-navigating-doc/57066937#57066937)