# Vim + tmux + WSL shows squares and strange characters when navigating doc

Tags: vim, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am able to use vim within Windows Ubuntu subsystem without issues.

Then when running Vim within tmux, and typing text most of the characters come up as weird squares with a quotation mark inside instead of the actual letter.[This is a screen shot of the vim text][1]

[I have a similar behaviour][2] within the console when highlighting text within tmux (Ctrl+b+[).

Comment: Maybe `tmux -u` solves this, to force the terminal to use UTF-8?

Comment: I have just tried it. Unfortunately still the same result.

Comment: What terminal is this running in?

Comment: Not sure in what terminal run the linux subsystem within Windows 1. But when running `ps -o 'cmd=' -p $(ps -o 'ppid=' -p $$)` within my tmux I get "tmux" terminal. If I run it within my terminal before I enter tmux i get "/init", is that the terminal?

Comment: I am not familiar with vim; maybe this might be informative: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14028/utf-8-not-working-on-vim

Comment: I am running it within the WSL terminal. When typing `echo $TERM`, I get "screen-256color-bce"

Comment: For the wsl-terminal, find a setting pertaining to the character encoding, and set it to UTF-8.  Also check the tmux.conf file for settings related to the character encoding, and make sure they are set for UTF-8.

Comment: When you create a new file in vim, and you type characters, do they show up fine? If you save a test file, close it, and then reopen it, do the characters display fine?

Comment: In the WSL terminal, what is the output from `file <file_with_funny_characters>`?

Comment: And what is the output from `xxd <file_with_funny_characters> | head -n1`? (Only paste that here if the contents of your file are NOT sensitive).

Comment: In wsl-terminal, make sure that right-click > Options > Text > Character set > is set to UTF-8.

Comment: I am able to see the file ok after save it and reopen it. file "myfile.txt", returns ASCII text. And `xxd ...` returns 00000000: 6466 7366 6473 6661 7364 660a            dfsfdsfasdf.

Comment: That content differs from the screenshot...  Does it display correctly, without any funnies?

Comment: the first character "d", doesnt display, it display a funny character instead. And yes, I have created a new file different from the screen shot, but the behavior is exactly the same

Comment: Try to create a small file with random text, where these characters appear. Try to remove normal text before those characters, so that they appear near the beginning of the file. After that, save the file but first make a screenshot. Then run `xxd <your_file> | head -n5` (or another small number of lines) and paste those lines here at the end of your question, together with the screenshot.

Comment: Did you check all character encodings in wsl-terminal, tmux and vim, like I advised?

Comment: Yes, they are all set to utf-8

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related with setting the TERM within my bashrc like the following:
`export TERM=screen-256color-bce`

After commenting out that line, my Term was set to screen-256color and it just  worked fine.

Not sure why that was causing it

Comment: You're likely seeing this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/832

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different settings, and the only thing that worked for me was to use windows terminal with tmux and vim.

We can then set the following alias

`alias tmux='tmux new "export TERM=screen-256color; $SHELL"'`

Answer (score 0):

I m using windows 10 + msys64\ucrt64 + tmux + neovim 0.9

I had strange char too.

My fix was to add in .bashrc :

```
export TERM="xterm"
```

Note : you may break some other program by doing this.